# returning a struct type

Tags: c, struct, return

```
struct name_strucutre()
{
    char cName[] = "hello";
    int iCode, i = 0;
    struct sign_in items[6];//array of six structure variables

    Fpointin=fopen("namepass.txt","r");

    if (Fpointin == NULL)
    {
        printf ("File does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            fscanf(Fpointin,"%42s %d",items[i].name, &items[i].password);//read all values from the file into th structure
        }
        printf("Here is the sign_in structure\n");//print the entirety of the sign_in structure
        for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            printf("name: %s\ncode: %d\n\n", items[i].name, items[i].password);
        }
    }
    fclose(Fpointin);
    return items;
}
```

This function is supposed to return the structure `sign_in` is this a safe way of passing a structure back to the main? I have to compare user inputted values to the values of the structure and this is the only way I can think of going about it.

Comment: it should not even compile. you are not declairing a function, you are declairing a structure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, you have to define return type as `struct sign_in` and not simply `struct`. Second, it is better to return pointer to structure especially in your case with array of structures (not single object).

Comment: _better_? do you mean the current approach is somehow correct?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Read again my answer. "It is better to return pointer (instead of structure itself)". Technical mistakes in example are other thing (read "First").

Comment: _Technical mistakes in example are other thing_.. really? What are we doing here?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Once again - READ all words in my answer. It is not necessary to quote it entirely! And - where is your answer of question? Explain the problem or it is better to post quarrelsome comments.

Comment: You still did not get my point, instead you are busy defending your stance. I repeat, better is not the word you want to use there. The code is (and will be) simply wrong for making attempt to return address of local variable. If you still do not (_want to_) understand, I'll be wind... :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh "First, you have to define return type as struct sign_in and not simply struct". If you prefer to re-write the whole function, do it. I give directions for thinking to author and do not write someone's homework.

Comment: So, you're saying, fixing a syntax error will change the local variable scope? Wow....

Comment: What you're suggesting, will compile and invoke UB, even worse, with current code, atleast it will not compile.... :)

Answer (score -3):

1. The function declaration should be either `struct sign_in* name_strucutre()` or `struct sign_in& name_strucutre()`
2. You cannot return a structure created on stack that happens at `struct sign_in items[6];` inside the function.

Comment: what if I just pass it to another function instead of returning it?

Comment: Why not? It is possible to return automatic structure. Array of structures is other thing, but single element can be return value.

Comment: Returning a structure allocated on stack from a function? thats something new

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin No, it's really not something new. It's plain old standard C.

Comment: Can you explain why my answer was downgraded?

Comment: @Michael You mention `struct sign_in&` which is C++, and thus totally wrong for a C question. That's one reason I think your answer deserves a down-vote.